# Using OSGeo4W program on Windows to convert Sweref99 to WGS84 and get the result in a file

Tags: osgeo4w, cs2cs, results

I will use cs2cs to convert between Sweref99 and WGS84. It works fine, but I want the result table in a file and not just in a DOS window on the screen. How ??

Hans Johansson

Comment: Where do you have your source coordinates? In a text file, Excel, database...?

Comment: The source coordinates is in text file, the conversion works all right, but I want to have the result coordinates in a file too. Not on the DOS screen.

Answer (score 1):

`cs2cs` takes one or more filenames as arguments, see the [documentation](http://proj4.org/apps/cs2cs.html) for more detail.

> One or more files (processed in left to right order) specify the source of data to be transformed. A - will specify the location of processing standard input. If no files are specified, the input is assumed to be from stdin. For input data the two data values must be in the first two white space separated fields and when both input and output are ASCII all trailing portions of the input line are appended to the output line.

Comment: Do you understand what that all means? I must admit that I don't.

Comment: yes, or I would not have posted it, you need a file with at least 2 data values per line - the first 2 are lat/lon or x.y and the rest will be copied over.

Comment: Could you write a complete working example with one input and one output file?

Comment: I did not find any other way than to redirect the output with ">".  `cs2cs +init=epsg:4326 +to +init=epsg:3857 cs2cs_input.txt > cs2cs_output.txt`.